# Установка TCP-соединения

Tags: tcp

Когда устанавливается tcp-соединение, клиент отправляет SYN, сервер выделяет ресурсы для соединения и отправляет ACK-SYN клиенту, и потом уже клиент отправляет ACK серверу. Это называется "тройное рукопожатие".

`При получении пакета SYN сервер выделяет часть своих ресурсов для установления нового соединения. Обработка множества пакетов SYN рано или поздно, затребует все ресурсы сервера и сделает невозможным обработку новых запросов Такая атака получила название «отказ в обслуживании» ( Denial of Service (DoS)).`

Что в этой схеме подразумевается под термином "сервер выделяет ресурсы"? Какие такие ресурсы? Можно максимально подробно, или хотя бы ссылку?

Answer (score 1):

Точный ответ зависит от конкретной реализации серверного сетевого стека, но как минимум:

1. Расходуется сетевой ресурс на отправку данных
2. Расходуется оперативная память на отслеживание новых соединений
3. Расходуются ресурсы процессора на обработку входящего трафика

Конечно, тут может быть множество других ресурсов, таких как дескрипторы или какие-то внутренние структуры, специфичные для конкретной реализации.

Comment: сервер выделил порт, запомнил ассоциацию client ip port - self port для данного соединения, и хранит это у себя в памяти. Это и есть выделенный ресурс? Так это же  ничтожно малый объем информации, его можно хранить тоннами и держать 100500 соединений одновременно

Comment: А это уже зависит от реализации. Если мы делаем микросхему, которая должна прикинуться целым сервером, то и 64кб памяти хватит для всего, тем более, что можно даже номер порта не всегда хранить - к примеру, отвечать по любому порту одинаковой информацией. Но в реальных ситуациях, информации нужно куда больше, особенно когда нужно отбиваться от возможных атак в реальных условиях.